# Unable to use proper path with VBA SaveCopyAs

Tags: excel, vba

Unable to `SaveCopyAs` to proper path using vba:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "Rounds " & Month(Sheet4.Cells(1, 2)) & " - " & Year(Sheet4.Cells(1, 2))
```

The code is saving just short of the file path.  Folder is located on a folder on the desktop but the new file is being saved to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

`Path` returns the folder the workbook is saved under. Sounds like you want:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Rounds " & Month(Sheet4.Cells(1, 2)) & " - " & Year(Sheet4.Cells(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run this:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path
End Sub
```

you would see something like: `C:\Users\Username\Desktop` in the immediate window.
Thus, if you run your code like this:

`Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path & "Rounds " & Month(Sheet4.Cells(1, 2))`

You would most probably see something like this:

`C:\Users\Username\DesktopRounds 12` and this is not what you need. There is obviously a `/` missing after the Desktop. Thus, put it there and try further:

`ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Rounds " & Month(Sheet4.Cells(1, 2)) & " - " & Year(Sheet4.Cells(1, 2))`

Comment: @user11865658 [You may consider marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)